# Java getting a final score total of correct answers + boolean repeat

Tags: java

Trying to figure out how to print a score total of all the correct answers, pretty basic, also trying to include a boolean repeat function so I can ask the user to either "play again" or "quit".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class GameVer1 {
public static void main(String []args) {




String inputName;
System.out.print("Enter your name here...");
inputName = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.print("Hi "+ inputName + ", Welcome!");

//boolean repeat = true;

        int tries = 0;
        int score = 0;
        int count = 0;


    do{
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Random randomNumberChooser = new Random();

        int ranNum1;
        ranNum1 = randomNumberChooser.nextInt(12)+2;
        int ranNum2;
        ranNum2 = randomNumberChooser.nextInt(12)+2;
        int response = (ranNum1 * ranNum2);

        String question;
        System.out.println("How much is " + ranNum1 +" x " + ranNum2 + "?");
        question = userInput.next();
        tries = tries + 1;

        if(userInput == response){
        System.out.print("Correct!");
        userInput = response;
        count = count + 1;
    }



}while(tries <10);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you having problems with?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Having a problem with "response" int, I can't use it in an if bracket and I'm not sure why, that seems the simplest option

Comment: My answer below should help with that specific problem.  I don't think you need the line `userInput = response;` near the bottom.  That would give you another error.  I will add this comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first convert the input to an `int` for comparison, like so:

```
int num = userInput.nextInt();
```

You will then be able to compare `if (num == response) {` and you will no longer get the error.

**EDIT**

Also, as far as I can tell, you can remove the line `userInput = response;` as it would also give you an error, but even so, the `userInput` is read again at the next iteration of the loop.